# Logical Operators in Tweepy Filter

Tags: python, filter, tweepy

I'm hoping to track tweets that contain a certain set of words, but not others. For example, if my filter is: "taco" AND ("chicken" OR "beef").

It should return these tweets:

```
-I am eating a chicken taco.
-I am eating a beef taco.
```

It should not return these tweets:

```
-I am eating a taco.
-I am eating a pork taco.
```

Here is the code I'm currently running:

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import time
import json

# authentication data- get this info from twitter after you create your application
ckey = '...'                # consumer key, AKA API key
csecret = '...'             # consumer secret, AKA API secret
atoken = '...'   # access token
asecret = '...'     # access secret

# define listener class
class listener(StreamListener): 

    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            print data   # write the whole tweet to terminal
            return True
        except BaseException, e:
            print 'failed on data, ', str(e)  # if there is an error, show what it is
            time.sleep(5)  # one error could be that you're rate-limited; this will cause the script to pause for 5 seconds

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status

# authenticate yourself
auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["taco"])  # track what you want to search for!
```

The last line of the code is the part I'm struggling with; if I use:

```
twitterStream.filter(track=["taco","chicken","beef"])
```

it will return all tweets containing any of the three words. Other things I've tried, such as:

```
 twitterStream.filter(track=(["taco"&&("chicken","beef")])
```

return a syntax error.

I'm fairly new to both Python and Tweepy. Both [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21519351/tweepy-tracking-multiple-terms) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13299206/how-to-track-more-than-a-single-term-in-tweepy) seem like similar queries, but they are related to tracking multiple terms simultaneously, rather than tracking a subset of tweets containing a term. I haven't been able to find anything in the [tweepy documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/tweepy/html/).

I know another option would be tracking all tweets containing "taco" then filtering by "chicken" or "beef" into my database, but I'm worried about running up against the 1% streaming rate limit if I do a general search and then filter it down within Python, so I'd prefer only streaming the terms I want in the first place from Twitter.

Thanks in advance-

Sam

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Twitter does not allow you to be very precise in how keywords are matched. However, the [track parameter documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/guides/basic-stream-parameters) states that spaces within a keyword are equivelent to logicals ANDS. All of the terms you specify are OR'd together.

So, to achieve your `"taco" AND ("chicken" OR "beef")` example, you could try the parameters [`taco chicken`, `taco beef`]. This would match tweets containing the words `taco` and `chicken`, or `taco` and `beef`. However, this isn't a perfect solution, as a tweet containing `taco`, `chicken`, and `beef` would also be matched.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron- this will work nicely. As an aside, do you know if there is a way to return all words beginning with a sequence of characters?

For example, in R if I wanted to return "plant", "planting", and "planted", I would be able to query "plant+".

Comment: I don't think so, sorry. Like I said in my answer, the API is pretty coarse-grained in how it lets you filter.

Comment: @AaronHill For example, to filter both words `hello` and `bye` (logically OR), we should use `track=['hello,bye']` or use `track=['hello', 'bye']` or maybe no differences?